# Bernoulli Numbers and radius of convergence

Tags: power-series, bernoulli-numbers

consider the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{e^x-1}$.

Since the function $\frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{(k+1)!}$ has a taylor expansion with $\frac{1}{f(0)}\neq 0$ we know that $f(x)$ must have a taylor expansion in some neighborhood of 0, i.e. we can write

$f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} B_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$ in some neighborhood $(-\delta, \delta)$ with $\delta>0$.

In Wikipedia and other sources, I've read the radius of convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} B_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$ is actually $(-2\pi,2\pi)$. Is that true and how con one prove it? Further, does the Taylor series converge for all $\vert x \vert< 2\pi$ against f(x) ? How can I see it?

I hope someone can explain it to me.

Best regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although it is possible to get distracted by connections to subtler things, observe that $f(z)=z/(e^z-1)$ is holomorphic on $|z|<2\pi$, has simple poles at $\pm 2\pi i$, and is holomorphic on $\{|z|<4\pi\}$ with $\pm 2\pi i$ removed. A power series converges on the largest disk in which a function is holomorphic, so the radius of convergence is $2\pi$.

Comment: In other words (I agree with them) the best way to study real power series is to use complex power series.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, indeed! The power series of the function $f(z)=1/(1+z^2)$ at $0$ powerfully illustrates this point, to my mind: the function is well-behaved on $\mathbb R$, (rhetorically) why should the power series fail to converge beyond $\pm 1$? :) Well, because its behavior in the complex plane is a genuine phenomenon that constrains its behavior on the real line, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try computing the radius of convergence $r = \limsup \sqrt[n]{B_n}$.  It is related to the [Riemann Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers).

$$ \frac{B_n}{2n!} = \zeta(2n)\frac{2 }{(2\pi)^{2n}}$$

with $\zeta(2n) \to 1$ and $2^{1/n} \to 1$.

I wonder then, how to write the analytic continuation, since $f(x)$ is clearly defined outside of $|x| < 2\pi$.

Comment: I don't understand the last comment: the analytic continuation is simply the function $x/(e^x-1)$ we started with (well, analytic but for simple poles at nonzero multiples of $2\pi i$).

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Can you give me a working infinite series when $x = 3\pi$ ?

Comment: Not an elementary closed form, but for each $n$ you can compute the $(x-3\pi)^n/n!$ coefficient by differentiating $x/(e^x-1)$ $n$ times and substituting $x=3\pi$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Sorry that wasn't fair.  You could expand around $x = n \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ for $|n| > 2\pi > 6$.  There could be a "transition map" between the series for various $n$.